# Difference between setting a variable using @EnvironmentObject and @MainActor

Tags: swift, swiftui

Let's say that I have the following:

```
@MainActor
final class NetworkController: ObservableObject {
    @Published var authState: AuthState = .guess
}
```

I understand that if I have a function inside that class that sets the `authState` to other state, that would trigger the UI response, but is that the same as me setting it in a view using `@EnvironmentObject`?

Example 1: Setting it inside the class

```
@MainActor
final class NetworkController: ObservableObject {
    @Published var authState: AuthState = .guess

    func setState() {
        authState = .login
    }
}
```

then either in another viewmodel or onAppear in a view calling that function.

Example 2: Setting it in the environment

```
struct SessionControllerView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject networkController: NetworkController

    var body: some View {
        Text("Something")
            .onAppear {
                networkController.authState = .login
            }
    }
}
```

Thanks

EDIT:

This is an overlooked question, Apple is making some changes between these two, they are not the same.

Comment: Yes, it will have same effect, ie. no difference.

Comment: If they have no difference, why when I have a class marked with `@MainActor` and I modify a `@Publisher` in that class, it says: `Publishing changes from background threads is not allowed; make sure to publish values from the main thread (via operators like receive(on:)) on model updates.` shouldn't it publish like the main thread? @Asperi